# Fields of Study Introduced by Leonhard Euler

Tags: education, math-history, big-list

Leonhard Euler is called the *Father of Graph Theory*. He also started off the studies of *Calculus of Variations*.

Which all are the other mathematical/science disciplines that evolved as an independent field of study because of him?

Quick Google search did not return any good documents on it, the closest I could find is this [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_things_named_after_Leonhard_Euler#Notes) and [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contributions_of_Leonhard_Euler_to_mathematics), but both of them doesn't explicitly mention disciplines that were started off by him, far as I read.

Comment: Newton and the Bernoullis had considered the brachistochrone problem before Euler, so I don't think the two contributions in your first paragraph are of equivalent status.

Comment: @Chappers, quoting *Differential Equations and the Calculus of Variations* by *Lev Elsgolts*, page 294: *"The calculus of variations began to develop in 1696 and became an independent mathematical discipline with its own methods of investigation after the fundamental works of Euler (1707-1783), whom we may justifiably consider the founder of the calculus of variations."*

Comment: And as you pointed out, usage of phrasal verb "started off" in the question is misleading. Can't think of a better way to quote it there at the moment.

Comment: Perhaps http://hsm.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @Ihf, I did think about it! Math.SE is more of a home for me among SEs, thought I'll give it a shot here before I go elsewhere! Export or should I create a new thread there?

Comment: I dk whether Euler was the first to extend a real function to the domain $\mathbb C$ by using its power series, but he did a lot with it, e.g. his famous $e^{ix}=\cos x +i\sin x.$ His collected works,on paper, will fill a room.